# merge two list on same field logic

Tags: java, list, java-8

I have two list and two list have same field. Some students have two houses in different countries. I want to increase id field of studentList2 while merging two list. I can use two for loop to check all list but do you know better solution for this problem.

List1 is studentList1

```
schoolId | id | countryCode | cityCode
5555       1      20            1
5555       1      24            2
5555       2      1             3
5555       3      1             3
5555       4      1             3
```

List2 is studentList2

```
  schoolId | id | countryCode | cityCode
  6666       1      20            1
  6666       1      24            2
  6666       2      20            1
  6666       2      24            2
  6666       3      20            1
  6666       3      24            2
  6666       4      20            1
  6666       4      24            2
  6666       5      1             3
  6666       6      1             3
```

My expectation is

```
  schoolId | id | countryCode | cityCode
  5555       1      20            1
  5555       1      24            2
  5555       2      1             3
  5555       3      1             3
  5555       4      1             3
  6666       5      20            1
  6666       5      24            2
  6666       6      20            1
  6666       6      24            2
  6666       7      20            1
  6666       7      24            2
  6666       8      20            1
  6666       8      24            2
  6666       9      1             3
  6666       10     1             3
```

I can use two for loop to compare list fields but I want to find better solution.

Comment: Please post you attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: Add to your question the code you tried or the one you think it is not good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to add all of dataset A to a new list and compute the id offset by referencing the final item in dataset A.

Once you have the offset, you can clone and append all of dataset B to the new list.

```java
static List<Student> combine(List<Student> left, List<Student> right) {
    List<Student> combined = new ArrayList<>(left);
    final long idOffset = combined.get(combined.size() - 1).getId();
    combined.addAll(right.stream()
            .map((student ->
                    student.toBuilder()
                            .id(student.getId() + idOffset)
                            .build()))
            .toList());
    return combined;
}
```

### Full example

```java
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.ToString;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class DataProcessor {
    private static final String[] COLUMN_NAMES = { "schoolId", "id", "countryCode", "cityCode" };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Student> datasetA = parseDataset(DATASET_A);
        List<Student> datasetB = parseDataset(DATASET_B);
        List<Student> combined = combine(datasetA, datasetB);
        printDataset(combined);
    }

    private static String datasetHeaderFormat = "%8s | %4s | %11s | %8s%n";
    private static String datasetRowFormat = "%8d %6d %13d %10d%n";

    static void printDataset(List<Student> students) {
        System.out.printf(datasetHeaderFormat, COLUMN_NAMES);
        for (Student student : students) {
            System.out.printf(datasetRowFormat,
                    student.getSchoolId(),
                    student.getId(),
                    student.getCountryCode(),
                    student.getCityCode());
        }
    }

    static List<Student> combine(List<Student> left, List<Student> right) {
        List<Student> combined = new ArrayList<>(left);
        final long idOffset = combined.get(combined.size() - 1).getId();
        combined.addAll(right.stream()
                .map((student ->
                        student.toBuilder()
                                .id(student.getId() + idOffset)
                                .build()))
                .toList());
        return combined;
    }

    static List<Student> parseDataset(String dataset) {
        return Arrays.stream(dataset.trim()
                        .split("\n")).skip(1)
                .map(DataProcessor::parseLine)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static Student parseLine(String line) {
        String[] tokens = line.trim().split("\\s+");
        if (tokens.length != 4) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected a token count of 4");
        }
        return Student.builder()
                .schoolId(Long.parseLong(tokens[0]))
                .id(Long.parseLong(tokens[1]))
                .countryCode(Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]))
                .cityCode(Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]))
                .build();
    }

    @Builder(toBuilder = true)
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    @Getter
    @ToString
    private static final class Student {
        private long id;
        private long schoolId;
        private int countryCode;
        private int cityCode;
    }

    static String DATASET_A = """
            schoolId | id | countryCode | cityCode
            5555       1      20            1
            5555       1      24            2
            5555       2      1             3
            5555       3      1             3
            5555       4      1             3
            """;

    static String DATASET_B = """
            schoolId | id | countryCode | cityCode
            6666       1      20            1
            6666       1      24            2
            6666       2      20            1
            6666       2      24            2
            6666       3      20            1
            6666       3      24            2
            6666       4      20            1
            6666       4      24            2
            6666       5      1             3
            6666       6      1             3
            """;
}
```

#### Output

```
schoolId |   id | countryCode | cityCode
    5555      1            20          1
    5555      1            24          2
    5555      2             1          3
    5555      3             1          3
    5555      4             1          3
    6666      5            20          1
    6666      5            24          2
    6666      6            20          1
    6666      6            24          2
    6666      7            20          1
    6666      7            24          2
    6666      8            20          1
    6666      8            24          2
    6666      9             1          3
    6666     10             1          3
```